# Getting Query timeout in Couchbase while performing aggregation on 100m records using spark

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am getting Query timeout when reading 100m records from cocuhbase bucket using spark

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to get help, I would recommend providing some code samples of what you have going on.

Comment: There's not much to go on here, but I'll try to help.  If you're using couchbaseQuery() to do the query, it takes an optional second timeout parameter.  For a large 100m record query you will very likely need to increase that.